# Port forwarding in ZTE Router Model: ZXHN F670L

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, port-forwarding

The settings not appearing and I have been trying to set up some ports but I cannot find it in any settings.

Comment: Check under Internet--> Security --> Port forwarding

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Easiest Way to Get an Open Port on the ZTE ZXHN F620 Router](https://portforward.com/zte/zxhn-f620/)